# Building DYLD from apple's source

Tags: xcode, macos, open-source, dylib, dyld

I am trying to build the open source DYLD, published by Apple here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-97.1/

I copied down every single file and tried building the XCode project, but am stuck on a missing file.

i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: /usr/local/lib/system/libc.a: No such file or directory

I checked the XCode project settings and this flag is being specifically set, yet there is no such file anywhere on my filesystem. There is a libc.dylib however.

From other posts I have read it seems that Mac OS X usually doesn't use this libc.a file, and yet it is referenced by this project.

Does anyone know where I can get this file or why it is used?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I found some info here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2008/Oct/msg00016.html. Am going to try to build via darwinbuild.

Comment: I got past the error and now stuck on missing references, such as: "_open$UNIX2003", etc. I'm trying to use SDX 10.6 but maybe I need an older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull libc from http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/ and build the static form. You may wind up having to build the full [LibSystem](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libsystem) and use its build-libc.pl script, depending on what you're trying to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the source for libc from [apple open source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/). You should be able to compile the static library with this.